# HTML5 game canvas very large map?

Tags: php, html, canvas

I'm using hexagon tiles.
And I wanna make, really really big map just like a world map.

one tile is 60px width and 40px height.
and my world will have thousand tiles for a line (from left to right).

But this is normally very hard to load.
What can I do to use very large map? how can I solve the lag problem?

Answer (score 4):

Don't "draw" tiles that are outside of the visible viewport.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, don't draw tiles outside the viewable area.

You may also run into problems simply iterating through so much data and doing the calculations to work that out, you could try pre-rendering the background as svg or even a none vector image format.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **LOT of pixels** in a map that's 6000+ pixels wide for 1 row!

Normally .jpg compressed tiles are the most bandwidth effective image for backgrounds.

But in your situation, you might try using SVG for your map background instead of pixel-maps.

SVG remembers the only the lines and curves of your map.

So think of SVG as an image where you don't have to "remember" the white space pixels between the lines.

That means the client computer has far less fully-rendered background to put into memory.

For example:

This SVG world map is 656k to download and still only about 1mb fully rendered in a viewbox:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/Worldmap_location_NED_50m.svg

This .png of the same map is 160k download but is 15mb+ when fully rendered to 6000+ pixels wide.

SVG is ideal for "tiling" also.

It has a built-in `viewbox` that lets you view only the portion of the map represented by your canvas.

SVG has the added benefit of scaling without much loss of image quality. (zooming without pixelizing)